Is it posible to achieve background loading in single thread in Godot 4.3?
I'm developing a Godot 4.3 web game, and the idea is using the web single thread new mode that avoids problems with SharedArrayBuffer (Adam Scott talks about these problems here)
However, with single thread my game freezes every time it loads any resource or changes scenes, so I'm looking for a background loading solution that works in single thread.
I've found this stackoverflow answer that explains how to do it, but sadly it seems to use obsolete methods that are not available in Godot 4.3, like load_interactive and poll.
The official documentation only talks about background loading with multithreading (If I understood it correctly, keep in mind I'm a begginer) so I've been asking reddit, the Godot forums, and even if people seem to be interested in knowing the answer, nobody has been able to give me one so far.

Based on what I've seen and know so far, what you're asking for isn't supported at the moment because load() is blocking (e.g. doing it in a coroutine / await still blocks main thread). I suggest coming up with loading screens or scenes to ease the loading experience for the players.
Maybe you can load 90% of what you need at the beginning of the game so that the entire experience does not need further resource loading (which was done by majority of flash games that I used to play back in the day).
I know you mentioned you want to avoid SharedArrayBuffer, but in platforms like itch.io I am able to toggle SharedArrayBuffer (it's a setting in the publish form) for some demo 3D games that I've published in the past, which has solved some of the performance problems with the demo game.
